# Scripts Not Fully Executing When Run From Another Program in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple BAT script that is called by another program ([Tripp Lite PowerAlert Local (PAL)](https://www.tripplite.com/products/power-alert-local)).

shutdown.bat contents:

```
echo "ON BATTERY" >> onbattery.log
wsl ssh root@server shutdown now
```

I have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installed so that I can easily run Linux commands and the above runs just fine when I run it manually via CMD Prompt or Power Shell. However, when I provide the path of the script for PAL to run it, the SSH command doesnt get executed (server doesnt shut down). Its worth noting that I generated keys so no password is needed. It does generate the onbattery.log file, so I know PAL is running the script.

My first thought was a permissions issue, so I set the PAL service to use the main account login (same account I ran it manually in), but that didn't seem to have any affect. Im not really sure what else to consider or try as a test at this point.

Why would a script run as intended only when manually executed?

Example showing PAL setup which recommends BAT files:
[image: PAL setup with script entry on battery event]

Comment: The first thing that jumps out to me is that it specifically states, above the entry field you've highlighted in yellow, "Enter the complete path of the program or command script to execute", so why have you decided not to enter any path whatsoever? Also as your provided script content is writing to a file, and that file also does not have an absolute path, your script is lacking either a specific command to define the current working directory, or the location for `onbattery.log`.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, Compo. The path was removed because I put the script in the same location as the PAL.exe based on a recommendation I read on a similar issue from another forum where the OP couldn't get it to execute at all. It didnt help in my situation. As I mentioned, the script does run as the creation of the local onbattery.log can only occur if it is executed. So, it seems pathing isn't an issue. The onbattery.log file is created in the same location as the script as expected. The location is "C:\Program Files (x86)\TrippLite\PowerAlert\engine".

Comment: How did you determine it is not working? Did the battery log get created? Did you check `c:\eindows\system32` for the log? Perhaps build in some debugging into the script to see if indeed it executed. I.e `wsl ssh root@server shutdown now >"%temp%output.log" 2>&1` then check for output.log in `%temp%`

Comment: Not a solution here, but still: do not call your batch file `shutdown.bat` since there is a command `shutdown.exe`…

Comment: @Gerhard, I tried what you suggested and just got an empty log file. Would this indicate that there were no errors?

Comment: So that means your script is in fact launching. Perhaps check permissions now on the commands.

Comment: @radensb Just wanted to let you know that I deleted my answer.  I didn't read your question closely enough -- Since you say that running the `bat` file manually is working, then by extension the `ssh` command must be working.  My next thought was the same as yours - Something related to the user it was running as.  I'm still thinking you should add some more logging into the bat file (redirect some of the output from the `wsl` command to the log as well).